# Scala String Variable Substitution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark code written in scala. Spark Reads meta tables (already in spark as temp table) which stores the SQL to be executed.

Problem I am facing is that we have queries which uses variables (defined in scala code)

I tried different methods but I am not able to substitute variable with value.

```
var begindate= s"2017-01-01";
var enddate =  s"2017-01-05";

Msg.print_info(s"begin processing from ${beginDate} to ${endDate}");


//Reading SQL from MetaData table stored in spark as meta_table (temp table)

val dynamic_read_sql = s"""
        select SQL_TEXT
        from meta_table""";

val dynamic_sql_query = sqlContext.sql(dynamic_read_sql);
val check_query = dynamic_sql_query.first().getString(0);

Msg.print_info(s"check_query = $check_query");
```

I am geting  sql displayed correctly.

```
// date is also temp table in spark
select * from date where load_date >= '${begindate}' and load_date <='${enddate}'
```

Next step is to execute this sql

```
dynamic_sql_find = sqlContext.sql(check_query);
```

But it fails to replace '${begindate}' and '${enddate}' which are already defined in code. Hence, returns 0 records.

I tried to store the store in another variable.

```
val replace_check_query = s"${check_query}"
```

But, It did not replace the variable.

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @radumanolescu correctly said, begindate and enddate are substituted only at compile time. To substitute these at runtime you can replace substrings manually:

```
val dynamic_sql_query = sqlContext.sql(check_query).replace("${begindate}", begindate).replace("${enddate}", enddate)
```

Answer (score 5):

The substitution of the variables `begindate` / `enddate` into a string (e.g. `s"From $begindate to $enddate"`) is set up at compile time, i.e. your expression is translated into something like `"From " + begindate + " to " + enddate`. This translation cannot be done at runtime with a random string that is only known at runtime.
The values `begindate` / `enddate` are only substituted at runtime, i.e. the expression `"From " + begindate + " to " + enddate` is computed at runtime, but the translation from `s"..."` to `"..." + "..."` is done at compile time.

Other observations:

- you do not need `var` or `s"..."` for begin/end. Do this: `val begindate = "2017-01-01"`
- please execute `Msg.print_info(dynamic_read_sql)` and let us know the output